# The spiral equation in system of coordinates

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, spin-geometry

I have a dependence $r(t)=\sqrt[3]{a t^2}$, where r is the distance and t is the time (which is cartesian coordinate, argument from ox axis). The initial distance is $r_{0}$ and it is decreasing over time. How would it look like in polar coordinates? It will be a spiral?

Comment: None of these tags is appropriate.  These are all very advanced subjects.  What course are you taking?

Comment: I’m new on this forum and I don’t know how to tag proprely.

Comment: Is $t$ what we usually call $\theta$?  The angular coordinate?

Comment: t is cartesian coordinate, argument from ox axis.

Answer (score 0):

Any increasing function of $\theta$ gives a spiral.

[image]

Beware that the plot is only for $\theta\ge0$.

Comment: What is the equation for decaying spiral? I mean the change of radius is measured from initial radius $r_{0}$ to 0.

Comment: @PawełChmolewski: $\rho=\sqrt[3]{at^2}$ is given.